# No method named `subtractPointFromPoint` found for type `()` in the current scope

Tags: rust

I have started creating a gaming graphics engine using [this article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/lets-build-a-3d-graphics-engine-points-vectors-and-basic-concepts--gamedev-8143). I chose Rust because I have heard about it and it sounds perfect for creating games. The only problem is I have no experience whatsoever. I have used Python, JavaScript, Java and HTML before.

This is the code I have written so far:

**point.rs**

```
// Point class

// Operators
struct point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    z: i32,
}

// Variables
pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32) {
    let mut point = (x, y, z);
    //return point;

    impl point {
        fn addVectorToPoint(self: &point, (x, y, z): (i32, i32, i32)) {
            let mut x = x + &self.x;
            let mut y = y + &self.y;
            let mut z = z + &self.z;
            let mut point = (x, y, z);
        }

        fn subtractVectorFromPoint(self: &point, (x, y, z): (i32, i32, i32)) {
            let mut x = &self.x - x;
            let mut y = &self.y - y;
            let mut z = &self.z - z;
            let mut point = (x, y, z);
        }

        fn subtractPointFromPoint(self: &point, (x, y, z): (i32, i32, i32)) {
            let mut x = &self.x - x;
            let mut y = &self.y - y;
            let mut z = &self.z - z;
            let mut vector = (x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod point;

fn main() {
    let point1 = point::new(1, 2, 3);
    let point2 = point::new(3, 2, 1);
    let newPoint = point1.subtractPointFromPoint(point2);
    println!("{:?}", newPoint);
}
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `subtractPointFromPoint` found for type `()` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:27
  |
6 |     let newPoint = point1.subtractPointFromPoint(point2);
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `impl` is defined inside the `new` function, and is a function-level item which cannot be accessed outside the function. Defining the `impl` as a module-level item will ensure that you can access the methods defined in other places.

Comment: Adding up to what @EvilTak said, the function `new` is not returning anything, and would more idiomatically written as a method. Moreover, the naming conventions are to use CameCase for data types (`Point`) and snake_case for functions and methods (`add_vector`).

Comment: I'm rather surprised that `impl Point` even compiles inside a function. You can even implement a trait inside a function. oO

Comment: @CodesInChaos All top-level *item*s (functions, structs, enums, traits, implementations, const, static, etc.) are also possible inside of a function. You can even do N-level nested functions. EvilTak [doesn't seem to be correct about the visibility, however](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3b523dac93489c9723771c36fec679df&version=stable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't expect that you can just arbitrarily type code into your editor and it will work. Programming languages have rules around syntax and structure that you have to follow. Additionally, the Rust community has put *a lot of effort* into creating good guides.

For example, if you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), specifically the chapters on [defining and instantiating structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-01-defining-structs.html) and [method syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html), you will learn that functions that return a value have to declare the return type in the function signature:

```
pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32) -> point { /* ... */ }
```

You also have to

- Actually create your struct (`let mut point = point { x, y, z }`)
- Actually return your struct from the function

This can be simplified to just:

```
pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32) -> point {
    point { x, y, z }
}
```

If you *don't* declare a return type, that's the same as saying that a function returns the empty tuple, also called the *unit type*:

```
pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32) -> () { /* ... */ }
// Idiomatically written as
pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32) { /* ... */ }
```

That's where the `` found for type `()` `` part of the error message is coming from. The unit type is also the value of a Rust statement — an expression terminated with a `;`. That's why your function body compiled — it ended with a `;`.

---

All sorts of other issues are present:

- Use `PascalCase` for types like `Point`.
- Use `snake_case` for variables and methods.
- Move the constructor function to be an *associated function* of `Point`.
- Instead of duplicating the name `Point`, the constructor can return `Self`.
- Use `&self` instead of `self: &Point`
- None of your methods *do* anything. They take a value, perform some operations, then  throw away the result. You probably want to take a `&mut self`.
- Your methods don't accept a `Point` but instead a tuple of numbers.
- You are trying to change your `point1` variable but it's not marked as mutable
- You need to implement `Debug` to be able to print out a `Point`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    z: i32,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, z: i32) -> Self {
        Point { x, y, z }
    }

    fn add_vector_to_point(&mut self, (x, y, z): (i32, i32, i32)) {
        self.x += x;
        self.y += y;
        self.z += z;
    }

    fn subtract_vector_from_point(&mut self, (x, y, z): (i32, i32, i32)) {
        self.x -= x;
        self.y -= y;
        self.z -= z;
    }

    fn subtract_point_from_point(&mut self, Point { x, y, z }: Point) {
        self.x -= x;
        self.y -= y;
        self.z -= z;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut point1 = Point::new(1, 2, 3);
    let point2 = Point::new(3, 2, 1);
    point1.subtract_point_from_point(point2);
    println!("{:?}", point1);
}
```

Consider implementing [`AddAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) and [`SubAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.SubAssign.html) instead of these custom methods.

You could also implement [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) and [`Sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Sub.html):

```
impl std::ops::Sub for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn sub(self, other: Point) -> Point {
        Point::new(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y, self.z - other.z)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let point1 = Point::new(1, 2, 3);
    let point2 = Point::new(3, 2, 1);
    let point3 = point1 - point2;
    println!("{:?}", point3);
}
```